# Direct output of sed find and replace to file

Tags: unix, command-line, replace, sed, find

I have the following command to find and replace from the current directory tree down, "OldString" with "NewString".

```
sed -i 's/OldString/NewString/g' `grep -ril 'OldString' *`
```

Can anybody advise how I might direct the output of this to a file, for verification:- The output file would then show the parent files + filepaths of which files were modified?

e.g. output file:

```
/home/htdocs/index.html 
/home/htdocs/file_containing_oldString.html
```

Comment: What about `for file in $(grep -ril 'OldString'); do sed -i 's....g' $file; done` ?

Comment: Hi @fedorqui, would you mind directing this as an answer?

Comment: To be clear - "OldString" is NOT a string, it's a regexp. Thinking of it as a string can/will bite you.

Comment: Hi Barney, I think @EdMorton 's answer is pretty pretty more powerful than my comment!

Answer (score 3):

The UNIX command to find files is named `find`, not `grep`. The GNU guys screwed up royally when they added that `-r` option. To find & replace a regexp with a string would be:

```
tmp=/usr/tmp/tmp$$
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' 0
find . -type f -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    sed 's/OldRegexp/NewString/g' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

The only caveat with that is it won't work if your file names contain newlines - if they do then either rename them (preferably) or look at `find -print0` and `xargs -0`.

You can get rid of explicitly naming the tmp file by using `sed -i` if you prefer.

Now, if you want a list of which files were changed, you can just do something like:

```
tmp=/usr/tmp/tmp$$
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' 0
> logfile
find . -type f -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    sed 's/OldRegexp/NewString/g' "$file" > "$tmp"
    if [ $? -eq 0 -a diff -q "$tmp" "$file" ]
    then
        printf "%s\n" "$file" >> logfile
        mv "$tmp" "$file"
    fi
done
```

If you decide to use `sed -i` (personally, I wouldn't) then create the tmp copy of the file before the sed and use that for the diff.

Comment: Is it working fine? I suspected that using `find ... | while ...` would make the `while` block not to have access to `$tmp` as it is opening a new shell. If that was the case (I haven't tested), I would suggest to do `while ... done < $(find ...)`

Comment: The loop will have access to the variable $tmp, it just wouldn't be able to change it outside of the context of the subshell.

Comment: +1 for royal screw up. Lemme get some napkin to wipe coffee off my screen.